# Should foreign keys be represented directly when mapping database tables to classes?

Tags: class-design, class-diagram

Ok, in my database I have a table Event and a table Room. Each Room can have many Event.

```
Room table
roomID-roomName
1     - cafe102
...

Event table
eventID- Time  -type -roomID
1      - 11:20 - 1   - 1
2      - 15:20 - 1   - 1
...
```

So I want to crate a Class structure that mimics the DB structure.

```
public class Event{
  private int eventID;
  private String time;
  private int roomID; // or
  private Room room;
  public Event(){
  }
  /// all set and get methods here
} 

public class Room{
  private int roomID;
  private String roomName;
  public Room(){
  }
  //all Set and Get methods here
}
```

My question is, in the `Event` class, should I have type `private int roomID;` or     `private Room room;`?

Also is there any reason to put `private Event event;` into `Room` class? Or does it just depend on the need and there is no standard?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Answer (score 3):

ID is a way for the database to connect a room to an event, there's no need to duplicate that in the class. So I'd definitely choose `private Room room;`. This will create a much better object model than having a bunch of IDs.

As to your other question, I'd say it depends on your needs whether you need a two-way reference or not. From modeling point of view it seems more natural that an event has a room assigned and the room doesn't need to know the events. But if you need to show the booking status of a particular room or something like that, then adding the reference might be a good idea.

However, you should notice that it's a one-to-many relationship, so one room can have more than one event. So if you want the `Room` class to know the related events, your variable needs to be `private List<Event> events;` (of course it can also be some other structure than a list).

Comment: +1 You should *never* expose database IDs in your classes. They're an artifact of the storage medium. If you have to go to a distributed database system and all your IDs become UUIDs, then you'll have to change your code. Yes, someplace in your data layer you'll have to deal with them, but they shouldn't be in your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you would need to have the roomID on the Event on the code itself (you use this relationship just for the DB). I would rather say that you can point directly to the Room Object. (private Room room );

Now, the second question why would you put an Event attribute to a Room? I would say that you can create in your application a list of Events which have the same room, but I do not understand why you would say that a Room have events. Maybe the concept of the room is the list of events it contains?

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a reference to an `Event` in your `Room` class I see no reason why you shouldn't. In ORM's such as EntityFramework in .NET, ActiveRecord in Ruby, this is allowed, so I guess it is OK to do it.